# Cant figure out where to place message.property files

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, internationalization

I keep getting

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'title.login' for locale 'en_US'.
```

wherever I put my messages_en.properties file.

Can't figure out where it goes or whats missing.

My folder arrangement is currently like this (just as I saw in a tutorial):

[image]

And my initializer is like this:

```
package br.com.sirious.energyquality.Initializer;

import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class MainInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainInitializer.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addServlet("spring", new DispatcherServlet());
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }


    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

My spring-context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.sirious.energyquality." />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/energyquality" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="br.com.sirious.energyquality.interceptors.AuthenticationInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>


</beans>
```

And my jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title><spring:message code="title.login"/></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Whats wrong there?

Also, can I configure that Authentication interceptor of mine inside my initializer?

Comment: Did you try renaming the file `messages_en.properties` to `messages_en_US.properties`?

Comment: your ".properties" file is not in the classpath. by default Spring will use the path /src/main/resources to load properties. Yours has no main folder.

Comment: Where do I make this main folder?

Comment: Right click src, then create folder named "main" then drag and drop your existing "resources" folder in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redid somethings and Added a Resources folder outside of src. Now it works.

Also, fiddled with some configs at the main initializer,
following this tutorial: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistry.html